# It seems like WHERE clause does not work in my VBA code

Tags: sql, vba, date, where-clause

```
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim str SQL AS String
Dim strConn As String
Dim FUMR_date As Date

FUMR_date = "2019-02-20 11:00"
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [initial DB] " & _
        " WHERE (date(LNT) < date(FUMR_date) )"


strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Alldata.mdb;" 
rs.Open strSQL, strConn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText
```

There is a table named Initial DB in Alldata.mdb. And LNT is column name of Initial DB table. Date information is in the LNT column.

What I am trying to do is to call dataset in which LNT value is earlier than FUMR_date. But my code does not work at all. Always I got runtime error.

I also tried

```
    " WHERE (Datevalue(LNT) < Datevalue(FUMR_date) )"
```

and it didn't work. However,

```
    " WHERE (Datevalue(LNT) < Datevalue(now()) )"
```

this code works. I don't know why. Please let me know the problem.

Comment: Does this query work if you write this in Access and substitute values for your variables? If it does work in Access then look more into the values going into the query. Try using `Debug.Print variable` to see what values you are supplying

Comment: You are not actually using the variable for FUMR_Date, is this intentional?  Or should this be `strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [initial DB] " & _
        " WHERE (date(LNT) < date(" & FUMR_date & ") )"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command string is send straight to the database. However, `FUMR_date`  is a VBA variable and not known in your database.
For a quick solution, write 
 `" WHERE (date(LNT) < date('" & FUMR_date & "') )"` - This will put in the content of the variable (as string) into the Where-Clause.

However, it would be much better to use a ADODB-Command and add a ADODB-Parameter for the date so that you don't have to take care about date formats

Comment: Thank you for your comment. However, it still does not work. But if I change date -> Datevalue, your suggested code works. Why is that???

Comment: I'm not very familiar with MS-Access, but I think `date()` is a parameter-less function that returns the current date